# Is ok to have Entity Framework inside Domain layer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oop

I have a project with the following structure:

**Project.Domain**

- Contains all the domain objects

**Project.EntityFramework**, ref `Project.Domain`

- Contains Entity Framework `UnitOfWork`

**Project.Services**, ref `Project.Domain` and `Project.EntityFramework`

- Contains a list of Service classes that perform some operations on the Domain objects

**Project.Web.Mvc**, ref to all the projects above

I am trying to enforce some Business rules on top of the `Domain` objects:

For example, you cannot edit a domain object if it's parent is disabled, or, changing the name of an object, `Category` for example, needs to update recursively all it's children properties (avoiding / ignoring these rules will result in creating invalid objects)

In order to enforce these rules, i need hide all the public properties `setters`, making them as **internal** or **private**.

In order to do this, i need to move the `Project.Services` and `Project.EntityFramework` inside the `Project.Domain` project.

Is this wrong?

PS: i don't want to over complicate the project by adding `IRepositories` interfaces which would probably allow me to keep `EntityFramework` and `Domain` separate.

Comment: *Adding IRepositories interfaces which would probably allow me to keep EntityFramework and Domain separate* is the correct solution. It will make your code testable, loose-coupled and you will be able to switch data access implementation easily

Comment: If your view model and your data model are the same, you can easily refactor one with an affect on the other. Keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

> PS: i don't want to over complicate the project by adding IRepositories interfaces which would probably allow me to keep EntityFramework and Domain separate.

its really a bad idea, once i had this opinion but honestly if you dont program to abstraction it will become a pain when the project becomes larger. (a real pain)
IRepositories help you spread the job between different team members also. in addition to that you can write many helper extensions for Irepository to encapsulate Different Jobs for example

```
IReopisotry<File>.Upload()
```

you must be able to test each layer independently and tying them together will let you only do an integration tests with alot of bugs in lower layers :))

Answer (score 1):

First, I think this question is really opinion based.

According to the Big Book the domain models must be separated from the data access. Your domain has nothing to with the manner of how storing the data. It can be a simple text file or a clustered mssql servers.
This choice must be decided based on the actual project. What is the size of the application?
The other huge question is: how many concurrent user use the db and how complex your business logic will be.
So if it's a complex project or presumably frequently modified or it has educational purposes then you should keep the domain and data access separated. And should define the repository interfaces in the domain model. Use some DI component (personally I like Ninject)  and you should not reference the data access component in the services.
And of course you should create the test projects also using some moq tools to test the layers separately.

Comment: Where do you create your implementations of your IRepositories? In your data layer?

Comment: @NeilSmith yes (or often named infrastructure layer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is wrong, if you are following Domain Driven Design, you should not compromise your architecture for the sake of doing less work. Your data-access and domain should be kept apart. I would strongly suggest that you implement the Repository pattern as it would allow you more flexibility in the long run.

Comment: Indeed, i want to use `DDD`. However, i will need to create a lot of code in order to implement `IRepository` interfaces, also knowing that i will probably never change `Entity Framework` with something else

Answer (score 0):

There are of course to right answer to whats the right design...
I would however argue that **EF is you data layer abstraction**, there is no way youre going to make anything thats more powerful and flexible with repositories.
To avoid code repetition you can easily write extension methods (for IQueryable<>) for common tasks.
Unit testing of the domain layer is easily handled by substituting you big DB with some in-proc DB (SqlLite / Sql Server Compact).
IMHO with the maturity of current ORMs like nHibernate and EF is a huge waste of money and time to implement repositories for something as simple as DB access.
Blog post with a more detailed reply; http://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer

Comment: The repository pattern fit to the separation of concerns and improve the testablility of the application.

Comment: There are tons of things one can do to improve a program - all of them are not worth the effort. Technology keeps moving forward.